# Best way to pass parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a business logic where I need to get data from my repository base on the Entry the I will pass to my repository. Here is my function

```
 public List<RiskLevelOfBreakdownItemsDto> GetRiskLevelOfBreakdownItems()
 {
        _RiskRegisterRepository = new RiskRegisterEntryRepository();
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        ids.Add(1); // 1 is for all open Risk
        ids.Add(2); // 2 is for all accepted Risk
        var riskLevel = _RiskRegisterRepository.GetRiskLevelOfBreakdownItems(ids);
        return riskLevel;
 }
```

I know my code above is against the SOLID principle. 
What is the best way to do the above code?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java when it is C#?

Comment: I suggest you to use Enum like: `Risk=1, AcceptedRisk=2 ...` and then `ids.Add(Risks.Risk); ids.Add(Risk.AcceptedRisk);` so you don't need to remember ids

Answer (score 1):

the first problem you are getting here is creating a new repository on a get, when it shall be a "singleton" and be "dependecy injected" or created on constructor or init method.

The rest of the code is Ok for me always that `_RiskRegisterRepository.GetRiskLevelOfBreakdownItems(ids);` is thread-safe